# Does anyone know how to fix this error Render process (17633) kill (OOM or update) wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing application

Tags: android, html, android-studio, apk, android-studio-3.0

I have been making a game for android and it is in HTML format then I have been trying to use android studio to turn it into an apk. But when I run the game I get no error and the application closes but when in the run process on android studio the error below comes up

E/chromium:  [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(89)] Render process (17633) kill (OOM or update) wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing the application.

I have tried lines of code to try and stop it but they haven't worked and I can't afford for this game to not help, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue when calling activity/fragment `onDestroy` and this activity contains a `WebView` ,so i have solved by calling `webview.destroy` when finishing activity/fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this setting to webview will fix issue

```
webView.setRendererPriorityPolicy(WebView.RENDERER_PRIORITY_IMPORTANT, false);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).